# Passing data from Activity to Service

Tags: java, android

I have a problem while passing String to a `Service` from `Activity`. What I am trying to do is to pass different Strings each time I call `Service`. I use `Intent` (putExtra() method each time). The problem is that each time it shows the first String that I passed. Is there a way to implement that?

Here is my `Activity`, `Broadcast Receiver`, `Service`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private EditText event;
private Button submit, date, time;
private static final int DIALOG_DATE = 1;
private static final int DIALOG_TIME = 2;

private int myYear = 2014;
private int myMonth = 8;
private int myDay = 16;
private int myHour = 6;
private int myMinute = 30;

private List<String> events;
private List<Calendar> dateTimes;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    event = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.event);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date);
    date.setOnClickListener(this);
    time = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
    time.setOnClickListener(this);

    events = new ArrayList<String>();
    dateTimes = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

    //List<Calendar> events = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id == DIALOG_DATE) {
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
        return datePickerDialog;
    }else {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, myCallBack1, myHour, myMinute, true);
        return timePickerDialog;
    }
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myCallBack = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        myYear = year;
        myMonth = month;
        myDay = day;
    }
};
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myCallBack1 = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
        myHour = hour;
        myMinute = minute;
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.date:
            showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);
            break;
        case R.id.time:
            showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
            break;
        case R.id.submit:
            String eventS = event.getText().toString();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, myMonth);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, myYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, myDay);

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myHour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myMinute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
//                calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BR.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("event", eventS);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            event.setText("");
            break;

    }
}

public class BR extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    intent.getExtras().getString("event");
    myIntent.putExtra("event", intent.getStringExtra("event"));

    context.startService(myIntent);
    Log.i("myLogs", "BR started");
}
}

public class MyService extends Service {

private NotificationManager mManager;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    String event = intent.getExtras().getString("event");

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "This is a test message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this.getApplicationContext(),0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(), event, event, pendingNotificationIntent);

    mManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Comment: It's done all the time. Hard to tell what you did wrong if you don't include code.

Comment: @323go here is my code

Answer (score -1):

A service can't be stopped until it's finish. You have to wait that your current service finish to send other data. You can collect all your strings and send them all together or wait until your background service finish